# Linux Mint 15 Doesn't detect Windows with update-grub

Tags: linux-mint, windows, grub2, bugs

I just installed Linux Mint 15, but `update-grub` doesn't detect Windows:

```
$ sudo update-grub
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-19-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.8.0-19-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
  No volume groups found
done
```

[Video showing Mint 15 (ubuntu raring) update-grub error/bug](http://youtu.be/QDxUeRHgU6g)

Comment: Please don't post videos, just copy/paste the output of the terminal. Also, `update-grub2` is just a link to `update-grub`, there is no point in running both. Where is you windows installed? Could you post your `/etc/fstab`?

Comment: # /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=87e9510b-daae-4746-a364-baee7d681dcb /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1

Comment: I have 3 Windows systems:
Windows XP: /dev/sda1
Windows 7: /dev/sda3
Windows 8 /dev/sda4

Comment: Please don't post added information in the comments, [edit] your original question instead.

Comment: Are you using a GPT or MBR partition table? Is this a UEFI system? Have you tried [adding a windows entry manually](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Grub2#With_Windows)?